Cardinality of dual of finite projective module
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $P$ be a finitely generated, projective $R$-module. Then the dual $P^*=\text{Hom}_R(P,R)$ is also finitely generated and projective. The question is whether it always holds that $|P^*|=|P|$. My attempts so far:
(1) The answer is positive if $P$ is free, in which case one has $P^*\simeq P$ as $R$-modules, so they definitely have the same cardinality. This is always the case if $R$ is a finite product of local rings, in particular if $R$ is finite.
(2) If $R$ is infinite, since $P$ is a direct summand of some $R^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $|P|\le|R^n|=|R|$ and $|P^*|\le|R^n|=|R|$. If $R$ is a direct summand of $P$, we have the lower bound $|R|\le|P|$ and $|R|\le|P^*|$, so $|P^*|=|P|=|R|$. But $|P|<|R|$ can indeed happen, e.g. if $R=R_1\times R_2$ with $|R_1|<|R_2|$, and $P=R_1\times 0$.
(3) If $P$ is an invertible $R$-module, we have $R\simeq\text{Hom}_R(P,P)$, and $\text{Hom}_R(P,P)$ injects into some $P^n$ because any $R$-linear map out of $P$ is determined by its value on finitely many ($n$) generators, so $|R|\le|P|^n$. If $|P|$ is finite then $|R|$ is also finite, in which case $P^*\simeq P\simeq R$. If $|P|$ is infinite, then $|R|\le|P|^n=|P|$, so by (2) we have $|P^*|=|P|=|R|$.
(4) It suffices to prove that one of $|P^*|\le|P|$ and $|P|\le|P^*|$ always holds, because $P$ being finitely generated and projective implies that it is reflexive ($P^{**}\simeq P$): replacing $P$ by $P^*$ in $|P^*|\le|P|$ gives the reverse inequality $|P|=|P^{**}|\le|P^*|$.
(5) There exists a commutative ring $R$ with an ideal $P$ that is projective, such that $P^*\simeq R$ and $|P|=\aleph_0<2^{\aleph_0}=|R|=|P^*|$; see my comment here. Even though $P$ is "small" as it is contained in $R$, it is also "large" as it is not finite. Probably nothing could go wrong like this when $P$ is finite, which this question assumes.
Thanks in advance for any ideas.
